# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load crashlytics from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, twitter-fabric

After add two lines in build.gradle I have the next exception:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load crashlytics from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.creardigitalm.samsungclub-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.creardigitalm.samsungclub-1]: findLibrary returned null

1. I add the dependency to my project-level build.gradle (apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'):

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
>
> apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

2. I add the plugin to my app-level build.gradle (classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'):

> ```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
>         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
>     }
> }
> ```

Fabric & google-services enter somehow in conflict and I do not know how to solve

Comment: I think the easiest way to use the `fabric` is `IDE plugins`. They are available to [download](https://fabric.io/login?redirect_url=%2Fdownloads) for Android Studio, Intellij, and Eclipse. These plugins will onboard your apps with Fabric. Also, you can follow the `Manual Setup` here:https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html

Comment: Yes, I did it like that. After set Fabric I added the lines that I show above, and then it throw the exception.

Comment: I got the exact same problem, did you find a solution yet?